# JavaScript Regex capture and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var whereClause = "p_id eq @p_id@ and idr_user_id eq @idr_user_id@";
```

I have the following regular expression to capture the tokens 
    /(@\w+@)/g

I would like to be able to replace each occurrence with a different value something like

```
whereClause.replace(/(@\w@)/g, projectID, userID);
```

Will this work? Any Ideas would be helpful...

Comment: You're exposing a where clause to be manipulated by the client? Sounds  like a security issue waiting to happen.

Comment: @adam0101, The where clause is filled in by by values queried from a sqlLite database not human input.

Comment: This will not work. The JS replace method only takes 2 parameters. Any additional parameters would be ignored. You'd have to create a RegExp object, run the regular expression against the string, and loop through the matches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could aim for something like this:

```
template(string, {key: value, key: value});
```

It could be implemented in a few lines using the `replace` callback:

```
function template(text, obj) {
  var regex = /@(\w+)@/g;
  return text.replace(regex, function(_, match) {
    return obj[match] || _;
  });
}

// Usage:
var str = 'p_id eq @p_id@ and idr_user_id eq @idr_user_id@';
var result = template(str, {p_id: 123, idr_user_id: 'ABC'});
//^ "p_d eq 123 and idr_user_id eq ABC"
```

If you need different regex or structure, you can create a simple closure around those, like:

```
function template(regex, fn) {
  return function (text, obj) {
    return text.replace(regex, function(_, match) {
      return fn.call(obj, match);
    });
  }
};

// Using an array
var myTemplate = template(/%(\d+)/g, function(x) {
  return this[--x];
});
var str = 'Hello %1, foo %2';
var result = myTemplate(str, ['world', 'baz']);
//^ "Hello world, foo baz"
```

Comment: And in case tokens which are not in the map should not be replaced, you could do `return obj[match] || _;`

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
whereClause.replace(/@\w+@/g, function(token) {
    switch (token) {
        case '@p_id@': return projectID;
        case '@idr_user_id@': return userID;
    }
    return token;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something somewhat similar to this before for dynamic error messaging.  To do it with what you are doing, it would go something like this.

```
function populateMessage(messageTemplate, replacementVals) {
    var newMessage = messageTemplate;

    for (var targetVal in replacementVals) {
        if (replacementVals.hasOwnProperty(targetVal)) {
            newMessage = newMessage .replace("@" + targetVal + "@", replacementVals[targetVal]);
        }
    }

    return newMessage;
}

var whereClause = "p_id eq @p_id@ and idr_user_id eq @idr_user_id@";
var replacementText = {"p_id": "SOME_TEXT_1", "idr_user_id": "SOME_TEXT_2"};
var outputValue = populateMessage(whereClause, replacementText);
```

The one of the pluses of this approach is that you can use different `whereClause` and `replacementText` variables for different situations and the replacement will only happen if the `.replace` finds a match for the defined keys.  So:

```
var whereClause1 = "p_id eq @p_id@ and idr_user_id eq @idr_user_id@";
var whereClause2 = "p_id eq @p_id@";
var whereClause3 = "idr_user_id eq @idr_user_id@";
```

. . . could all be "served" by:

```
var replacementText = {"p_id": "SOME_TEXT_1", "idr_user_id": "SOME_TEXT_2"};
```

. . . and result in valid messages.

It would also be REALLY easy to populate the `replacementText` object with dynamic values, if that was needed.